# which port(s) are used by DirectoryEntry?

Tags: c#, iis, port, firewall, directoryentry

My goal is to get the list of web site names from remote server. But I'm getting the exception:

> The RPC server is unavailable.

Here is the code:

```
    public List<string> GetWebSites(string serverIP)
    {
        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        DirectoryEntry Services = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("IIS://{0}/W3SVC", serverIP));
        Services.Username = "user name";
        Services.Password = "password";
        IEnumerator ie = Services.Children.GetEnumerator();
        DirectoryEntry Server = null;

        while (ie.MoveNext())
        {
            Server = (DirectoryEntry)ie.Current;
            if (Server.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer")
            {
                names.Add(Server.Properties["ServerComment"][0].ToString());
            }
        }

        return names;
    }
```

this works fine, when firewall is turned off on the machine.

What I need to know is, which port(s) are used by DirectoryEntry? 
or is there any other way to get web site names, without turning off firewall?

Comment: It will use a (broad) range of ports. If you need to force it to a specific port or smaller range, take a look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154596). If I am not mistaken, you'll also need UDP 389.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe LDAP protocol uses TCP no? Should be port 389 for non-ssl and 636 for SSL