# How to query Active Directory B if application server is in Active Directory A

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, active-directory, ldap

So heres my question. I have a Asp.net application with a form based authentication. I have users in my database but the users also has to be in the active directory.

The following code is for me to check if user is in the domain A

```
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
            de.Path = "LDAP://domainA.com";
            de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.None;
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(de);
            search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + account + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");

            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
```

This code work fine. The problem is client is requesting that domain B should also be able to connect to the application. So created the following code:

```
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
            de.Path = "LDAP://domainB.com";
            de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.None;
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(de);
            search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + account + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");

            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
```

Since my server is in domainA this does not work. Is there a way for me to query domainB knowing that the server is in domainA? I found an article saying trust needs to be setup for domainA and B but this domains shouldnt be linked. Its only for this application that they need this functionality.

P.S.  I might forgot to explain an important detail. domainA and B are not on the same network. But domainA can ping domainB

Comment: If trust between domains is not allowed, you need to provide credentials for user from domain B into DirectoryEntry constructor or use impersonation. This means that you have to store/request user name and password for user in domain B

Comment: @oldovotes sad didnt work....i got "server is not operational" error. Which is as generic as it can get. any idea as to why?

Comment: @oldovets I might forgot to explain an important detail. domainA and B are not on the same network. But domainA can ping domainB

Comment: Are you able to ping domain B via FQDN (domainB.com)? Are you able to ping a domain controller in domainB via FQDN from domainA? Seems like a network issue, related to DNS server.

Comment: @oldovets Sent 4 received 2. 50% loss on pinging the domainB.com

Comment: Can you connect to domainB from domainA via ldp.exe or other MS Active Directory tools? I believe, that you will be receiving the same error. You can use a retry pattern here. If it does not help, then the problem should be solved on the network level (dns server records, routes, maybe etc.hosts). It seems for me more like the network issue, than AD issue. Anyway, credentials for domainB definitely  must be provided

Comment: Proof that you have a reliable network connection before proceeding. 50% loss sounds like a problem. 
If you have two networks you should also check for a blocking firewall - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563485/which-ports-are-used-by-directoryentry

Comment: Did you try including a domain controller and a regular distinguished name for the naming context in the path? Under the premise you have a proper DNS and the naming context of your domain follows the default pattern, you would change line 2 to:

de.Path = "LDAP://DomainControllerOfDomainB/DC=domainB,DC=com";

Replace "DomainControllerOfDomainB" with a resolvable (FQDN recommended) hostname of a domain controller of domain B.

Note that anonymous access to Active Directory is not allowed by default, so that you might need to combine the solution with authentication mentioned by oldovets.

Comment: @oldovets tried using LDAP.exe. Was able to connect to the server but was not able to bind using the credentials they gave. Got a time out error. Any idea what that means?

Comment: @MatthiasLoerke Im sorry but i am unsure what you mean by domaincontroller.

Comment: @TheProvost: The Active Directory (AD) infrastructure contains servers that hold the domain data (users, computers, ous, etc) and respond to queries. These ones are called "domain controllers" (DC) and every AD must have at least one but can have multiple. The DNS-suffix (e.g. "domainA.com") normally resolves to the DC adresses, except for split DNS scenarios.

Comment: You have poor connection from domainA to domainB. You need to determine the problematic node, i. e. where in your network you lose packets, or contact your system administrator with your problem. You can start with running tracert command from cmd on server in domainA. This will allow you to see the server, which lose network packets. I'm not a sysadmin, so unfortunately cannot provide you more details on how to fix this network issue. Moreover, it depends on network configuration between domainA and domainB

Comment: @Matthias Loerke: I assume that if he contacts AD using serverless binding, the program uses locator service, which queries DNS server for domain controllers in domainB. My assumption is that DNS is a problemmatic node, so replacing domain with domain controller FQDN does not give him much. Netbios may also be an option here, but have serious doubts about it.

Comment: @oldovets: I agree that without a reliable network connection this won't work in any way. Having a proper DNS is generally also one of the important requirements when working with AD. As in this case the goal is to query a non-trusted  foreign domain, serverless binding does not seem helpful to me. My sample proposed a binding with server AND naming context, not just replacing the domain with a server FQDN. Got this working even using an IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying samples against a foreign domain, I noticed that the foreign DC is giving the error message "The server is unavailable" when using the wrong authentication type. Please try:

```
de.User = @"DOMAINB\user";
de.Password = "YourPassword";
de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.None;
```

Of course this results in an unsecured BASIC simple bind, which removes any encryption ADSI might offer. If this works, you should try a more secure authentication type that the server accepts.

An alternative might be using the "System.DirectoryServices.Protocols"-namespace which offers a more lightweight approach for AD access. I can provide you with a sample I you want to go in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide credentials that have permission to query AD on domain B.

```
var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domainB.com", "Username", "Password");
var search = new DirectorySearcher(de);
```